# How to get textbox array value to php post method

Tags: php

I have an html file with the following code:-

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function addTextArea(){
    var div = document.getElementById('div_quotes');
    div.innerHTML += "<textarea name='new_quote[]' />";
    div.innerHTML += "\n<br />";
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="1.php">
<input type="text" name="text_new_author" /><br />
<div id="div_quotes"></div>
<input type="button" value="Add Text Area" onClick="addTextArea();">
<input type="submit" name="submitted">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to store the textarea values in a PHP array. I am using the following code, this code will store only first textarea value. Does not store additional textarea.

1.php

```
if(isset($_POST['submitted']))
{               
foreach ($_POST['new_quote'] as $values ) 
{
echo $values;
}
exit();
}
```

In this code, I am getting only 1st Textarea values.

If I add 3 textarea and submit. I would like the following output:

```
$values1 = First Textarea value 
$values2 = Second Textarea value 
$values3 = Third Textarea value
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using normal variable that's why you are facing problem. Solution is-

```
$i =1;
foreach ($_POST['uploaded_files'] as $key=>$value ) 
   {
    $values.$i = mysql_real_escape_string($value);
    echo $values.$i;
    $i++;
}
```

Or you can directly use it:-

```
foreach ($_POST['uploaded_files'] as $value ) 
       {
        echo $value;
    }
```

Note:-

2nd one is more preferable.

Comment: When I add textarea using jQuery, name of textarea remain same. ie if I add three times textarea, my jQuery will use same code for three textareas.  <textarea id="input_clone" name="uploaded_files[]"></textarea>

So the following code is not working. Is there any other way sir?

Comment: which code is not working? first or second?Also a little bit change done in second one.And how many values are there. it will work fine.

Answer (score 1):

Is that a valid textarea format? (From your closed duplicate, you defined it like `<textarea name="" />`)  What happens when you define it like:

```
div.innerHTML += "<textarea name='new_quote[]'></textarea>";
```

Also, try escaping the `[]`  in your code like this:

```
div.innerHTML += "<textarea name='new_quote\\[\\]'></textarea>";
```

I remember a time using query where I had to do this in orders it to work, may or may not be your solution but worth a try.